# Clone table rows with select element inside td tag

Tags: javascript, select, copy, clone

I'm new to JS. I have a dynamic table (I didn't add the code for add and delete rows) which I want to show in another table. I try to clone every row. Everything is working but td tag with select element doesn't cloned properly. It shows the selected value or the first value if there is no selected. The idea of this clone is to show the table in modal form and the cloned table will be like a preview. Cloning happened when the modal foem is show. In code below I add the button for cloning table. I think, it doesn't matter in this case.

[This is the Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qdL0fo3v/).

Here is my code HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table" >
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td >#</td>
       <td >Description</td>
       <td >Qty</td>
       <td >Units</td>
       <td >Price without vat</td>
       <td >Vat %</td>
       <td >Total</td>
       <td >Del</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tr class="product">

     <td class="cloned" width="4%" >
       <input type="number" class="enumer" style="width:100%; border: none; padding: 0" disabled="disabled">
     </td>

     <td class="cloned" width="34%">
       <input type="text" class="item_product" style="width:100%;" name="product[]">
     </td>

     <td class="cloned" width="18">
       <input style="width:100%;" class="qty" id="qty" name="qty[]" pattern="[+-]?([0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]*)" type="text" value="0" required>
     </td>

     <td class="cloned" width="7%">
       <input  id="item_units[]" class="units" style="width:100%;" name="item_units[]" type="text" value="ks">
     </td>

     <td class="cloned" width="10%">
       <input class="price" style="width:100%;" id='price' name="price_unit[]" pattern="[+-]?([0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]*)" value="0" type="text" required>
     </td>
     <td class="cloned" width="7%" id="vat_td">
       <select class="vat" id="vat" name="vat[]" type="text">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
       </select>
     </td>
     <input class="hidden" hidden value="1" id="payer_vat_hidden">
     <td class="cloned" width="17%">
       <input type="number" style="width:100%; background: #dddddd;" class="amount" id="amount" name="amounts[]" readonly>
     </td>
     <td class="delTD" width="5%">
      <button type="button" style="width:100%;" id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
  
<button onclick="copyTable()">copy table</button>


<table class="table table-bordered" id="second_table" >
                          <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>#</th>
                                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                                <th class="text-center">QUANTITY</th>
                                <th class="text-center">UNITS</th>
                                <th class="text-right">PRICE</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Total</th>
                             </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
```

Here is my code Javascript:

```
function copyTable(){

  $("#second_table tr").remove();
  $("#table tr").each(function() {
  var $target = $("#second_table");
  var $tds = $(this).children(),
      $row = $("<tr></tr>");
      $row.append($tds.eq(0).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(1).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(2).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(3).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(4).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(5).clone())
          .append($tds.eq(6).clone())
          .appendTo($target);
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to also copy over the value of the <select>, manually. Use `$tds.eq(5).find('select').val()` or whatever column it is to grab it, then set it in the clone.

Comment: Note that using React instead of jQuery would be very useful here. This requirement is a prime example of why frontend frameworks exist.

Comment: Thanks. It should be the solution but I'm a bit confused about how to set this value to every row in the target table.

Comment: You are looping over each row. So inside the each function you need to 1. append the cloned cells up until but including the VAT cell 2. clone the value 3. append the rest of the cells. Don't use a huge statement chain; break it up.

Comment: Here's a React solution btw: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Here's an incomplete rewrite of your jQuery code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/98rmcLw3/

Comment: Thank you, Chris. You helped me a lot.